# Updating a data table

Tags: dataset, associations

**1. Example data**

I have a data table organized as an `Association` of `Association`s:

```
table =
  <|"fra" -> <|"19" -> 2359, "20" -> 2181, "21" -> 2321, "22" -> 2378|>, 
   "gre" -> <|"19" -> 184, "20" -> 167, "21" -> 181, "22" -> 192|>, 
   "ita" -> <|"19" -> 1729, "20" -> 1574, "21" -> 1684, "22" -> 1745|>, 
   "por" -> <|"19" -> 200, "20" -> 184, "21" -> 194, "22" -> 207|>, 
   "spa" -> <|"19" -> 1193, "20" -> 1058, "21" -> 1117, "22" -> 1177|>|>;

table // Dataset
```

[image]

For this table I import monthly updates which have the following form:

```
update =
  {<|"land" -> "gre", "22" -> 192, "23" -> 200|>,
  <|"land" -> "alb", "22" -> Missing[_], "23" -> 55|>,
  <|"land" -> "por", "22" -> 211, "23" -> 210|>};

update // Dataset
```

[image]

Sometimes values of the preceding year are revised. This is the case with `por`. The old value of `207` must be overwritten with `211`. It might also happen that new countries are added. This is the case with `alb`.

**2. Current solution**

My current solution looks like this:

```
lands = Union[Keys @ table, update[[All, 1]]];

years = Union[Keys @ table[[1]], Rest @ Keys @ update[[1]]];

missing = 
 Thread[lands -> Map[AssociationThread[years -> #] &, Table[Missing[], Length @ lands]]];

result = 
  Merge[{missing, Normal @ table, Normal @ GroupBy[update, First -> Rest, Last]}, Association];
```

**3. Expected result:**

```
result // Dataset
```

[image]

**4. Question**

The need for the extra `missing` table looks somehow amateurish to me, and I feel that a solution using f.e. `KeyUnion` or `JoinAcross` would be more appropriate. How can my code be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Using @eldo's suggestion in comments to define a function:

```
ClearAll[joinAssociations]
joinAssociations[tbl_, upd_] := Module[{key = Keys[upd][[1, 1]]},
  KeySort @ GroupBy[#, First -> Rest, Last] & @
   JoinAcross[KeyValueMap[<|Prepend[key -> #]@#2|> &]@tbl, upd, 
     key, "Outer", KeyCollisionFunction -> Right]]

Dataset @ joinAssociations[table, update]
```

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

Process `table` to give it the same *shape* as `update`:

```
table2 = KeyValueMap[<|Prepend["land" -> #]@#2|> &] @ table;
```

Use [`JoinAcross`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JoinAcross.html) to combine `update` and `table2`:

```
ds = Dataset @ JoinAcross[update, table2, "land", "Outer"]
```

[image]

Re-shape `ds` into the desired form:

```
ds[SortBy[#] /* GroupBy[#] /* Transpose, Map[KeySort @* KeyDrop[#]]] & @ "land"
```

[image]

**Note:** We can replace `JoinAcross[update,table2,"land","Outer"]` with

```
JoinAcross[table2, update, "land", "Outer", KeyCollisionFunction -> Right]
```

to get the same result.

Comment: If we name your `KeyCollisionFunction` variant `var`, the rest could even be shortened to `KeySort @ GroupBy[var, First -> Rest, Last] // Dataset`. Thank you for this excellent solution.